# I am not able to connect kafka to elastic search using Kafka elasticsearch connector

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I am following this article 
https://sematext.com/blog/2017/03/06/kafka-connect-elasticsearch-how-to/

I am getting error as

```
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: 
Failed to find any class that implements Connector and which name matches io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchSinkConnector  [...]
```

Comment: Did you copy the connector to Kafka's libs directory after building it? This error is what you would expect to see if for some reason the ElasticsearchSinkConnector is not in the classpath of Kafka Connect.

Answer (score 0):

As Sönke says in the comments, this is a classpath problem. You can side-step this by just using the [Confluent Open Source](https://www.confluent.io/download-center/) distribution which includes the Kafka Connect Elasticsearch plugin automatically with paths already in place.